# Norm of the one dimension real space

Tags: normed-spaces

I read that apart from a constant factor the absolute value is the only norm on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$. Why is that so?

Comment: just a hint: if you set $\|1\|=a$, how does this norm behave?

Comment: Then this norm gives $a$ times the absolute value of some number. But I don't understand what it means by "the only norm". When are norms considered equal? For example, if I define ∥1∥ = a and then ∥1∥ = b, won't there be 2 norms?

Comment: it is, as you said, "$\textbf{apart from a constant factor}$, the absolute value is the only norm"

That means that every norm is the absolute value multiplied by a constant

Comment: So there are more than 1 norm, just that each is a multiple of the others.

Comment: exactly,but that also means that they are equivalent, so they induce the same topology on the space. 

That's the reason for which we can study the norms apart from a constant factor

Answer (score 7):

This is a little more general perspective that I hope will be helpful with your intuition about norms. From this perspective the answer to your $1$D question will be obvious.

For every norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, there is a "unit ball" consisting of all the points that have norm less than or equal to $1$:
$$B = \{x : \lVert x\rVert \leq 1\}$$

In fact, this unit ball contains all the information there is to know about the norm.

Why? Well, if you want to find the norm of a vector, all you have to do is uniformly scale the unit ball up until it just barely touches the vector, then that scaling factor is the norm of the vector. This follows from the scaling property of norms. (See [Minkowski functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) for this statement in more technical wording.)

This leads to a natural question:

**Question:** What sort of shapes can a unit ball take?

**Answer:** The unit ball must be a balanced, convex, absorbing set.

This means,

- *Balanced:* the set is symmetric around zero, in the sense that if $u$ is in the ball, $-u$ must be too. This requirement comes from the scaling requirement for norms, using scaling factor $-1$.
- *Convex:* the set does not have any holes or "dents" in it, in the sense that for any two points in the set, the line segment between the points is also in the set. This requirement comes from the triangle inequality (after a bit of work).
- *(strictly) Absorbing:* the set can be uniformly expanded to contain any vector in the space. Also the set can be shrunk so that it it doesn't contain any particular point (except zero). This requirement again comes from the scaling law.

So this means unit balls can be things like spheres centered at zero, cubes centered at zero, ellipsoids centered at zero, and things like that.

---

Now in $1$D, the only convex sets are line segments, and the only balanced convex sets are line segments centered at zero. Furthermore, the absorbing requirement prevents the "degenerate" cases where a line segment is the single point at zero, or the whole real line.

Thus the only possible unit balls in $1$D are line segments that are centered at zero, and the only distinction possible between these unit balls is a constant scaling factor.

Comment: I understand that there can be many different types of norms (e.g. mean norm, Cartesian norm, supremum norm etc). Are there also other types of inner products apart from $(x ,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_jy_j$ ? Also, I read that for any inner product on a vector space V the function $\| x \| = \sqrt{(x,x)}$ defines a norm on the vector space. Why is that so? So does this formula work for all the different inner products?

Comment: The most direct way to see why these things are so is to verify that the formulas satisfy all 3 requirements of a norm.

Comment: If you know a little linear algebra, you can write any inner product between vectors $x$ and $y$ in the form $(x,y) = x^T M y$, where $M$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. So just like norms can be identified with balanced absorbing convex sets, inner products can be identified with symmetric positive definite matrices. The eigenvectors of this matrix form a basis in which the inner product acts like a weighted sum like your formula. Unit balls in inner product spaces look like ellipsoids where the axes are the eigenvectors, and the axis lengths are the eigenvalues.

Comment: How do you show the triangle inequality?

Comment: Well, by definition satisfying the triangle inequality would mean that $\sqrt{(x+y, x+y)} \le \sqrt{(x,x)} + \sqrt{(y,y)}$, or squaring both sides, $(x+y, x+y) \le (\sqrt{(x,x)} + \sqrt{(y,y)})^2$. So the game here is to start at one side of the inequality and apply whatever rules about inner products and and positive numbers and other tricks you know to get to the other side, with $\le$ symbols at every step of the way. Ie, $(x+y, x+y) \le \text{stuff} \le \dots \le \text{other stuff} \le (\sqrt{(x,x)} + \sqrt{(y,y)})^2$. Your challenge is to fill in those gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a Vector Space over the field $F$ where $F$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. One of the axioms that specify a Norm on a space is

- If $a \in F$ then $||a \cdot \underline v|| = |a| \cdot ||\underline v||$ for every $\underline v \in V$

  Now consider the cases when $a = 1$ and $a = -1$. See how this related to the definition of the Absolute Value Function in $\Bbb R$.